# Interpolating a HTML file in Ruby

Tags: html, regex, ruby

I am making a Ruby program that reads a HTML file with a "#{}" tag. here is the content of the HTML page:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>#{"Hello, World!"}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my Ruby code that I am using:

```
file = File.open("Path/to/file", "r")
content = file.read
puts content.match(/./om)
```

how do I change the code to interpolate the content so that the `#{}` in the webpage is replaced with the appropriate value?

Comment: what is the most elegant way to do this? I am making a Ruby Web Server that runs Ruby code like PHP

Answer (score 3):

The most elegant (and default) way to do that is to use a template language. Ruby comes with ERb that would solve you problem:

template.erb:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1><%=@greeting%></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

```
require 'erb'

template = File.read('path/to/template.erb')
@greeting = "Hola, mundo"
ERB.new(template).result(binding)
```

Comment: OP isn't asking for a template language, they are attempting to do this themselves.

Comment: In the comment he asks about the most elegant way to do that, it's not explicitly stated that he wants to build his own template lang.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose. Kind of hard to know what OP wants, especially given this sentence "I am making a Ruby Web Server that runs Ruby code like PHP"

Comment: That sentence let me think that OP just needs a solution, not that they want to do everything from scratch

Comment: how do I print that with it bounded?

Comment: prefix `ERB.new(template).result(binding)` with `puts`